# escaping dynamic html in jsf even when using <h:outputText ... escape="false">

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to post dynamic HTML to a jsf page, and it's escaping it, even though I say escape="false" in the output text tag.

I'm using primefaces 3.4.2
Tomcat 7.0.22.0

JSF page:

```
           <p:tabView id="editableArticleTabs" dynamic="true" cache="true" rendered="#{articleBean.allowEdit}">
            <p:tab id="readArticleTab" title="Read">
                <div class="article">
                    <h1 class="title">#{articleBean.article.name}</h1>
                    <div class="byline"> by #{articleBean.article.creator.username} </div>

                    <blockquote class="summary">
                        <h2>Summary:</h2>
                        <h:outputText value="#{articleBean.article.summary}" escape="false" />
                    </blockquote>

                    <div class="textBody">
                        <p><h:outputText value="#{articleBean.article.body}" escape="false" /></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </p:tab>
           </p:tabView>
```

What am I doing wrong? It's escaping everything.

Also, I print the text out in a System.out.printline in the getter method so I know for sure it's not stored in the database as escaped.

Edit:
Ok, here's the kicker. I try taking the text out of the tabs and it works. But I really need it to work inside the tabs.

Final edit:
It was my bad. I had two copies of the code, one rendered within a tab, the other without it. They had conditional rendering depending on the "editability". I set the escape flag in one and not he other. Major fail. Sorry 'bout that folks.